# P-table sorticon wont read while using NVDA tool

Tags: sorting, nvda

While using NVDA tool, when we click on sort icon it would change the ascending and descending value. But it wont read out the STATE of that. Like sorted ascending, sorted descending.

I want it to say as sorted ascending sorted and descending sorted.